# How to get nested elements?

Tags: jquery

I have some DOM structure:

```
<div class="model-A">
    <div class="some1">
        <div class="sub1"></div>
        <div class="model-B">
            <div class="some2">
                <div class="sub2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="model-C">
                <div class="some3">
                    <div class="sub3"></div>
                    <div class="model-B">
                        <div class="some4"></div>
                        <div class="sub4"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="some2">
                <div class="sub2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to get all elements of div which have 'model-B' class, but not other 'model-*' children? For example, result must be contain elements:

From first 'model-B'

```
<div class="some2">
   <div class="sub2"></div>
</div>
<div class="some2">
   <div class="sub2"></div>
</div>
```

And from second 'model-B'

```
<div class="some4"></div>
<div class="sub4"></div>
```

Comment: I tried .children, but it's return all childs of other model-*. I need only then elements, which relate with model-B class.

Comment: usually it would be nice if you could show something what u already tried...
anyway you could do something like $('.model-B').eq(0).children(':not([class^="model-"])')
- means grab all elements with class model-B,
- for my example get first (.eq(0))
- get children which don't have a class which starts with model-

so just remove .eq(0) and do it in a for loop -> done ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with the `:has` selector, like this:

```
$('.model-B>div').not(':has([class^=model])')
```

Demo:

```js
$('.model-B>div').not(':has([class^=model])').each(function () {
    console.log(this.outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="model-A">
    <div class="some1">
        <div class="sub1"></div>
        <div class="model-B">
            <div class="some2">
                <div class="sub2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="model-C">
                <div class="some3">
                    <div class="sub3"></div>
                    <div class="model-B">
                        <div class="some4"></div>
                        <div class="sub4"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="some2">
                <div class="sub2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks to you my knowledge has become richer, my friend.

Comment: Dear, may be you can say, how to do some this, but select elements via data attribue value (data-model="B")?

Comment: To select by attribute, you use square brackets, like `[data-model=B]`.

Comment: I found, that this code not work correctly, when I try to select model-A. Result contain all code, but need to exclude other model's. Look: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWrWPJ?editors=0001

Comment: I see what you mean, you want to exclude all models. So then do `:has([class^=model])`. I updated it also in the answer

Comment: I am sorry, I did not correctly formulate the question.I need to get some ```model-*``` with all nested childs, but exclude other elements with different model names (with its elements).  I think,this solution need recurcive DOM walking.

Comment: If your question is different, then please ask a new question. It will attract renewed attention then. But take care to describe your expectations precisely, with a good example.

Comment: Hi, friend, i do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947020/jquery-how-to-get-multiply-nested-elements