# JQuery: How to get multiply nested elements?

Tags: jquery

I have a DOM structure, with many nested elements. **Some of elements** have data attribute "model" and contain name of *model*. Important, than DOM structure can have several elements with the same model name. Also, omportant, that nested elements don't have сonstant structure - initially not know count of elements and order of nested elements.

[image]

Need to get element(s) by data attribute value (with concrete name, for examle: `data-model="B"`). Important, if requested elements contain other blocks with the data-model attribute with different name - these elements must be excluded from result. For examle - if we get `data-model="C"` (see pic), result should contain only blue elements (yellow must be excluded, because it contain data attribute model=n and n!="C").

And if we get by data-model="B", result must be contain all yellow elements, with all elements (with nested) of it, but exclude elements with different data-model value if it's present (not in pic, but you can see examle with "C" above).

Examle DOM structure:

```
<div data-model="A">
    <div>
        I'm into A
        <div data-model="B">Some text B in A</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div data-model="C">
            <div data-model="B">
                Some text B in C
                <div>some1</div>
                <div>some2</div>
                <div>someN</div>
            </div>
            <div>I'm into C</div>
        </div>            
    </div>
    <div data-model="B">Some text B in A</div>
    <div>I'm also into A</div>
</div>
```

Request examles:

If get element(s) with data-model="A", result contain:

```
<div>
    I'm into A
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div>I'm also into A</div>
```

...with data-model="B", result should contain:

```
Some text B in A
Some text B in C
<div>some1</div>
<div>some2</div>
<div>someN</div>
Some text B in A
```

...with data-model="C", result contain:

```
<div>I'm into C</div>
```

Comment: We tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42925067/how-to-get-nested-elements/42925452?noredirect=1#42925452, but this solution not work correctly.

Comment: it would be helpful if you provide expected output (from the input example). This likely sounds simple but via your explanation, everything becomes complicated.

Comment: Is there any chance that there is a nested model of the same type with the outer model (such as in the above example, instead of the model B nested in model C, the model A is inserted there (meaning the outermost model A nests another model A))?

Comment: I think no, in my current situation I don't need it. But, if your solution can resolve this collision, I do not mind about this)).

Comment: I understand that the result should maintain the ***hierarchy tree***, so if what I supposed above can be the case, the model C (between model A and the inner model A) is also included in the result. That's the unclear point. Not sure if that's expected.

Comment: Result may be can not maintain hierarchy, the main thing is that result must contain needed elements. And now i think that models with same name can't be nested, it really complicates the situation.